# Select * from a table using data from specific entry in table

Tags: sql

I have an author table

| au_id | au_fname | au_lname | city | state |

what i am trying to do is get a query of first and last names based on who lives in the same state as Sarah

Heres what I have so far:

```
SELECT AU_FNAME, AU_LNAME FROM authors WHERE "STATE" like 'CA'
```

I don't want to use a static state in my code, I want it to be based on the selected person  - Sarah in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Sub-Query` to find the state of `Sarah` and filter that `state`

Try this

```
SELECT AU_FNAME, AU_LNAME 
FROM authors 
WHERE STATE in (select state from authors where au_fname = 'Sarah')
```

Comment: wow, thank you that is awesome and it worked! and now i know about sub-queries!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AU_FNAME, AU_LNAME FROM authors WHERE STATE in (select state from authors where au_fname = 'sarah')
```

or

```
select a1.AU_FNAME, a1.AU_LNAME FROM authors a1
inner join authors a2 on a1.state = a2.state
where a2.au_fname = 'sarah'
```

Comment: The second query returns duplicates if there are several Sarahs in a state.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one "Sarah", then it is best to use `=` rather than `in`:

```
select a.AU_FNAME, a.AU_LNAME 
from authors a
where a.state = (select a2.state from authors a2 where a2.au_fname = 'Sarah');
```

Of course, if there could be more than one Sarah, then `in` is needed.  But `=` often has better performance, because the database engine knows to search for a single value.

Comment: Thank you, the performance part is good to know! This is a small db so there is only one Sarah so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is defined a bit vaguely, so based on a qualified guess, it seems asking for the solution to retrieve data rows (containing either ALL data fields, i.e. `SELECT *` as per the title, or just first/last names as per description, i.e. `SELECT AU_FNAME, AU_LNAME`) for the `states` related to some `au_fname` (e.g. Sarah) passed as a parameter to a SQL query. In the most general case, there can be **multiple different authors** with the **same first name** related to **multiple different states**. Based on this assumption, the query/sub-query may look like

```
SELECT * FROM authors 
WHERE STATE IN (SELECT [state] from authors WHERE au_fname = @afname)
```

The exact syntax may depend on the specifics of the Database used in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An inner join would be my first choice over a subquery... some db engines have poor performance with subqueries (older MySQL versions come to mind), but just about any engine ought to be optimized for an inner join:

```
SELECT a1.AU_FNAME, a1.AU_LNAME 
FROM Authors AS a1
INNER JOIN Authors AS a2 ON a1.state = a2.state
WHERE a2.au_fname = 'sarah'
GROUP BY a1.AU_FNAME, a1.AU_LNAME;
```

Comment: Returns duplicates if there are several Sarahs in a state.

Comment: @jarlh - so do all the others, except Gordon's, whose selects the first State it sees by default.  Add a group by if you want only distinct first/last names returned.  Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: MotoGP's answer doesn't. (And that GROUP BY may remove valid duplicates, i.e. Authors duplicates...)